# PHP Email form verification and writing to file

Tags: php, validation

Currently I have a form I am working on and I am trying to make it so the email will not post unless it is validated first. I have it working for name but whenever I try to do the same with email, it says 'Invalid email format' and doesn't write or post.

This is what I have working:

```
if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
} else {
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
        $nameErr = "Please type a real name"; 
    }else{
        $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
        //Record to file
        $myfile = fopen("names.txt", "a");
        $txt = $name . " ". $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] . "\r\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
        fclose($myfile);
    }
}
```

This is what I can't get working:

```
if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
     $emailErr = "Email is required";
} else {
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
    }else{
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    }
 }
```

Whenever I do this for email it results in "Invalid email format" even when I check to verify it is correct and it works with the $email variable define above the if statement.

If you see anything wrong or anything I could do to fix this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `$email` is assigned? I'd guess you should be using `$_POST["email"]` at `filter_var(`<--.

Comment: Yea, $email is assigned to $name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = ""; at the beginning of the document, sorry forgot to include that.

Comment: I mean it is assigned to the input value later though? e.g. `$email = $_POST["email"];`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are saving value in $email variable after checking for validation so save it before your validation in any variable or use this

```
if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
     $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! This makes a lot of sense and worked once I did this. Thanks a ton!